# How to revoke user in Hyperledger Fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I'm trying to revoke user by JAVA SDK

```
String crl = caClient.revoke(revoker, userToRevoke, "removefromcrl", true);
```

After executed the above line userToRevoke can still query and invoke normally. Why is it like that?

and what should I do next with this crl string?

Answer (score 0):

Your nodes must update periodically the `crls` folder under their MSP folder. Otherwise, revoked certificates cannot be detected by the MSP.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html#msp-setup-on-the-peer-orderer-side
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#generating-a-crl-certificate-revocation-list

And they should also be updated in the channel configuration, which is even more tedious.

Comment: Do you have any example of channel configuration for CRL ?

Comment: how to update the crls in local msp folder? Is there any example?